# Eclipse jar to an exe?

Tags: java, eclipse

I've searched far and wide, I can create my JAR using eclipse but when I run it, it doesn't run half of the program because it didnt import the API's, because the API's don't exist in the JAR.

I made a simple pac-man game (still learning java :O)
I compiled it into an executable JAR so I could use a program called 4J to turn it into an exe!

However, the JAR doesn't even run the game :/

Don't know what sources you need, so just ask.
Sorry I'm a newb D:

Comment: You must supply any 3rd party API's with your JAR, as separate files, simple as that. You don't need to create an .exe, but rather you need an installer of some type.

Comment: Don't make it an `exe`, it will not be runnable on good operation systems. :) Make an installer instead: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=installer+for+jar

Comment: I would suggest you manage your dependencies with a tool like [`apache maven`](https://maven.apache.org/) and its' [`jar plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/) and (because you're using eclipse) [`m2e`](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can supply third-party API within your **jar** file. This is so called **fat jar** approach (all classes will be put into one jar according to names of the packages). So you will deal with one jar file (then convert it to **exe**, or add shell scripts for specific operating systems which will just run `java -jar game.jar` - too many options).

As for Eclipse search for specific plugins. Or, as mentioned above, use Maven or tool that will give you a portable installer. It's completely up to you.